# Outer product with R arrays

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, linear-algebra

I have an array of dimension 3x1000. In truth each column is what's interesting. I want to use this to compute an array of dimension 3x3x1000, where a slab `i` is the outer product of the column `i` of the original array (in other words, `v %*% t(v)`). Is there a clean way to do this?

Below is a sample input matrix and output array, in the case of a 2x4 matrix.

```
mat_in <- cbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 4), c(5, 6), c(7, 8))
arr_out <- array(c(1, 2, 2, 4, 9, 12, 12, 16, 25, 30, 30, 36, 49, 56, 56, 64),
                 dim = c(2, 2, 4))
```

Comment: @jogo I have added an example input matrix and output array as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the desired result:

```
mat_in <- cbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 4), c(5, 6), c(7, 8))
array(apply(mat_in, 2, tcrossprod), dim=c(2,2,4))

### test:
arr_out <- array(c(1, 2, 2, 4, 9, 12, 12, 16, 25, 30, 30, 36, 49, 56, 56, 64),
                 dim = c(2, 2, 4))
arr_out - array(apply(mat_in, 2, tcrossprod), dim=c(2,2,4))
```